# Where should i run my grunt build step when building my docker image for staging and production environments?

Tags: node.js, deployment, docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose

I'm really struggling to figure out where i should put my grunt build step when building my docker image and deploying to dockerhub.

My workflow at the moment is as follows:

- Push branch to github
- CircleCI installs all dependencies, builds project, and runs tests on branch.
- Merge branch branch to staging branch
- CircleCI installs all dependencies, builds project, and runs tests on branch.

  - If tests pass, package the built files into the docker image with the source and also run `npm install --production`. CircleCI then deploys this `staging image` to dockerhub
- Tutum is linked to dockerhub and deploys my image to DigitalOcean whenever a new image is pushed.

***I do the same workflow as above, when merging to master, and a `production image` is created instead.***

It feels a bit weird that i'm created 2 separate docker images. Is this standard practice?

I've seen quite a lot of people including the grunt/gulp build step in their dockerfiles, but that doesn't feel right either as all the `devDependencies`, and `bower_components` will then be in the image along with the built code.

What's the best practice for running build steps and building docker images? Is it better to have CI do it, or dockerhub do it from the dockerfile? I'm also after the most efficient way to create my docker image for staging and production.

**Below is my circleCI.yml file, followed by my Dockerfile.**

circle.yml:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 4.2.1
  # Set the timezeone - any value from /usr/share/zoneinfo/ is valid here
  timezone:
    Europe/London
  services:
    - docker
  pre:
    - sudo curl -L -o /usr/bin/docker 'http://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/docker-1.8.2-circleci'; sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/docker; true

dependencies:
  pre:
    - docker --version
    - sudo pip install -U docker-compose==1.4.2
    - sudo pip install tutum
  override:
    - npm install:
        pwd: node
  post:
    - npm run bower_install:
        pwd: node
    - npm run grunt_build:
        pwd: node

test:
  override:
    - cd node && npm run test

deployment:
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build node
      # - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
      - tutum login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS -e $DOCKER_EMAIL
      - docker tag dh_node:latest tutum.co/${DOCKER_USER}/dh_stage:latest
      - docker push tutum.co/${DOCKER_USER}/dh_stage:latest

  master:
      branch: master
      commands:
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build node
        # - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
        - tutum login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS -e $DOCKER_EMAIL
        - docker tag dh_node:latest tutum.co/${DOCKER_USER}/dh_prod:latest
        - docker push tutum.co/${DOCKER_USER}/dh_prod:latest
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --production

COPY . /usr/src/app

#
#
# Commented the following steps out, as these
# now run on CircleCI before the image is built.
# (Whether that's right, or not, i'm not sure.)
#
# Install bower
# RUN npm install -g bower # grunt-cli
#
# WORKDIR src/app
# RUN bower install --allow-root
#

# Expose port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run app using nodemon
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the best practice for running build steps and building docker images? Is it better to have CI do it, or dockerhub do it from the dockerfile?

It's better to run the build steps themselves outside of docker. Thus the same steps work for local development, non-docker deployment, etc. Keep your coupling to docker itself loose when you can. Thus build your artifacts with regular build tools and scripts and simply `ADD` built files to your docker image via your `Dockerfile`.

> It feels a bit weird that i'm created 2 separate docker images. Is this standard practice?

I would recommend instead using exactly the image you have already built and tested on stage in production. Once you rebuild the image, you become vulnerable to discrepancies breaking your production image even though your stage image worked OK. At this point neither docker nor npm can deliver strictly reproducible builds across time, thus once it's built and tested gold, it's gold and goes to production bit-for-bit identical.

Comment: Ah okay, so i'm on the right track with using CI to run the build. Where i'm going wrong is with the ADD step. I think i'm lacking a fundamental understanding of how i should be using Docker. At the moment (as you can see above), i COPY the entire app dir into the image. My understanding is this would result in 2 separate images, as Staging would be commits ahead of Production, which is based off the master branch. I'm struggling to grasp the process of injecting code into the same image for both stage and production. Can you see where i'm going wrong and advise?

Comment: I've added my circle.yml file so you can see what i'm doing at the moment on CircleCI. I'd really appreciate you just combing through it and pointing out where i'm going wrong, and what i should change it to, as i feel rather lost at the moment and most articles online seem to be doing things wrong by putting the build steps into the dockerfile. Thanks @peter-lyons!

Answer (score 0):

Your circle ci should download all the dependencies and then create docker image from that downloaded packages. All testing is passed with the specified dependencies and should be carry forwarded to production. Once. The image is pushed to docker hub with all dependencies and tumtum will deploy the same to your production and as the dependencies are already downloaded it will take seconds to create containers.

Answering to your second query of building the same image. I would suggest to deploy the same image to production. This will guarantee you that what worked great on staging is also working the same on production.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with a sample Dockerfile and some pseudo steps for CircleCI of what you're proposing? I'm a little lost with the steps after you say, "All testing is passed with the specified dependencies and should be carry forwarded to production. Once."

Comment: There is a nice video on pluralsight showing how to deploy your docker container to production with tutum and circle ci